# Error when consuming packages from the Artifactory (v2 layout) with conan

Tags: artifactory, conan

I get following error message when trying to consume packages from a repo in the Artifactory:

> ERROR: 400: Conan is not yet migrated to V2 layout. Check logs for progress details.. [Remote: my-artifatory-repo]

I have noticed this error after upgrading the Artifactory from 6.3.0 to 6.23.13 version. Also found that since version 6.9.0 the Artifactory supports v2 binary package layout. It seems that the layout of packages in the Artifactory repositories has changed after upgrade.

According to [jfrog](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Conan+Repositories) (System Requirements) it is possible to use conan client versions with revisions mode enabled. I enabled revisions mode but it didn't help.
Artifactory CE for C/C++ 6.23.13 
Conan 1.30.0

**Edit**
I used following command to set env variable and then verified *conan.conf* file.

```
conan config set general.revisions_enabled=1
```

Comment: How did you enable revisions? Please, update you description with it. Also, you are running very old versions for both Artifactory and Conan, more than 1 year old each one. Please, update them to latest version, you can obtain both on https://conan.io/downloads.html, many things changed since then, including v2 support.

Comment: @uilianries thank you for the comment. I know that the versions are old but I am not the one who makes the decisions nor the only one who uses it. If it is not (easily) possible to use those old versions in combination we will need to consider updating them.

Comment: Understood. Consider @Muhammed Kashif suggestion, he an Artfactory expert and I work on Conan project. Also, try to keep Conan updated, because since 1 year ago many things related to V2 changed.

Answer (score 1):

I think after the upgrade the Conan migration from V1 to V2 is not completed which is causing the issue. To overcome this issue and let the migration trigger,

1. Connect to the artifactory database.
2. Run this query: 'delete from CONFIGS where CONFIG_NAME = 'artifactory.migration.conan.v2';'
3. Restart the Artifactory instance

This should trigger the migration. Please make sure to take the DB backup before performing the deletion.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: after running the query I've got output `delete from CONFIGS where CONFIG_NAME = 'artifactory.migration.conan.v2';
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
WARNING 02000: No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table.`
I also verified that I am connected to the right database. Is there any other possibility to trigger migration?

Comment: I think since there are no entries in the DB regarding migration, the migration is triggered  with every restart of the Artifactory but fails every time.